# YAML Syntax to get the value of an Env variable defined in context to a specific Environment in Git Actions

Tags: yaml, github-actions

Under my Git Repo Settings > Environments : I define an env name PPM_DEV, under this env PPM_DEV I define an environment variable named HOSTNAME and give it a value in the git configurations page.

Now what is the YAML syntax under GitActions WF to read the value of this variable ?
basically I may have 2 Env's defined PPM_DEV , PPM_TEST
but where do I set the Env context to pull the variable HOSTNAME from the PPM_DEV env ?

In the example below , I am trying to populate a variable VARHOSTNAME with the value of the Env variable HOSTNAME that is pre-defined against the Env named PPM_DEV

However it fails with
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/Ext_Conn_v2.yml (Line: 10, Col: 7): Unexpected value 'VARHOSTNAME'

```
name: Ext_Conn_v2
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  RunonVM:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: ppm_dev
      VARHOSTNAME: ${{ env.HOSTNAME }}
             
    steps:
    - name: Run a command
      
      run: | 
        echo "This workflow was manually triggered."
        echo "value of the variable HOSTNAME: " ${VARHOSTNAME}
        pwd
        echo "end of run"
```

Comment: See [`jobs.<job_id>.environment`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment).

Comment: Where does the HOSTNAME variable assignment fit in in the structure below ?

    
name: Ext_Conn_v2
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  RunonVM:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: ppm_dev
             
    steps:
    - name: Run a command
      HOSTNAME: ${{ env.HOSTNAME }}

      run: | 
        echo "This workflow was manually triggered."
        echo "value of the variable HOSTNAME: " ${HOSTNAME}
        pwd
        echo "end of run"

Comment: Depends on your workflow wherever you need it configured with the environment it has been defined under.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75437635/edit) your question and add that workflow under a code block. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is wherever I place it , it fails saying 
.github/workflows/Ext_Conn_v2.yml (Line: 13, Col: 7): Unexpected value 'HOSTNAME'

So what is the structure ?

Comment: From that comment, `HOSTNAME` doesn't look like under an `env` section. See [`env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env).

Comment: I just updated the main question with a code block. 
Appreciate you trying to help here

Comment: Sure thing. `environment` is just to specify the environment e.g. dev, prod, etc. You need to add an `env` section under the step where you want to use it. See this example: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-of-jobsjob_idenv.

Comment: Did you add `HOSTNAME` as an environment secret or variable? For secrets, you need to use the `secrets` context, and for variables, `vars`. See [Contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts) for more details.

Comment: Considering `HOSTNAME` as a secret defined under the `ppm_dev` environment, see your updated workflow [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxNjs0OgjAQhO99io3xig/QGzEaL2qiRo+EnzWgdNt0Wzgg724BMexlkp1vJkOpQgmPvdAkBUCr7ftZ6zYpKjapy0spXjrjwQo6CID1xFHAwWeenI/q1CG70UJqKqtJITkJxqikwAaWN1Ls0PDUFQGNA7ZaqZQKMVGhRoo5co8vh/P1doqPOwnrrgPG3KLjzfyFvv/BYZmEzz+JealhtQwvuvrVF3QwRsY=).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251836/discussion-between-chzdz-and-azeem).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv) to specify the environment variables or secrets using [`vars`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context) or [`secrets`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#secrets-context) contexts:

Here's an example with the `secrets` context:

```yaml
jobs:
  job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ppm_dev
    steps:
    - name: Command
      env:
        HOSTNAME: ${{ secrets.HOSTNAME }}
      run: |
        echo "HOSTNAME: $HOSTNAME"
```

See a linted example [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxNjs0OgjAQhO99io3xig/QGzEaL2qiRo+EnzWgdNt0Wzgg724BMexlkp1vJkOpQgmPvdAkBUCr7ftZ6zYpKjapy0spXjrjwQo6CID1xFHAwWeenI/q1CG70UJqKqtJITkJxqikwAaWN1Ls0PDUFQGNA7ZaqZQKMVGhRoo5co8vh/P1doqPOwnrrgPG3KLjzfyFvv/BYZmEzz+JealhtQwvuvrVF3QwRsY=).